# What are the most important papers regarding the epistemic significance of disagreement?

Tags: epistemology

There's been a debate recently about what is the right way to react to learning that you disagree with someone you take to be your epistemic peer. One approach is the "Equal Weight View". I associate the names Kelly and Christensen with this topic, but I don't know what are the most important papers on EWV and its critics.

Where is this topic (EWV) first broached and what are the most discussed critical papers/defenses of the view?

Answer (score 4):

I am making this answer CW so as to have it act as a repo for sources related to this phrasing of what is "disagreement". Please feel free to add to it while researching!

- [2004 Kelly, Thomas "The Epistemic Significance of Disagreement"(cited by 82)](https://www.princeton.edu/~tkelly/papers/disfinal.pdf)
- [2007 Weatherson, Brian "Disagreeing about Disagreement"](http://brian.weatherson.org/DaD.pdf)
- [2007 Shogenji, Tomoji "A Conundrum in Bayesian Epistemology of Disagreement"(cited by 3)](http://fitelson.org/few/few_07/shogenji.pdf)
- [2007 Jehle, David "Remarks on A Conundrum in Bayesian Epistemology"](http://fitelson.org/few/few_07/jehle.pdf)